# How to generate dynamic label and input field with unique id,name for dropdown selected item in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing a problem for creating a dynamic label and input field with unique id and unique name for each input when clicked from dropdown and
how can we unchecked dropdown or when remove button for select item is clicked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance

if two item selected from dropdown list that are [Invoice city] and [Invoice date] then for both the label and input field should be created  with unique ids** with remove button so that item get  unchecked from dropdown when remove button for select item is clicked

```js
var options = [{
    "text": "New 1",
    "value": "[Invoice city]"
  },
  {
    "text": "New 2",
    "value": "[Invoice Date]"
  },
  {
    "text": "Ocv 3",
    "value": "val 3"
  },
  {
    "text": "Option 4",
    "value": "Value 4"
  },
  {
    "text": "Option 5",
    "value": "Value 5"
  }
];
var selectBox = document.getElementById('multichecks');

for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
  var option = options[i];
  selectBox.options.add(new Option(option.text, option.value, option.selected));
}


$(document).ready(function() {
 function generate(option){
  var ops = $('#multichecks option:selected');
        var selected = [];
        $(ops).each(function() {
          selected.push([$(this).val()]);
        });
        $('#dvContainer').html('');

        $(selected).each(function(index, ops) {
          if (ops){
            $('#dvContainer').html($('#dvContainer').html() +'<div><label id="lbl'+ops+'"> '+ops+':</label><input type="text" id="txt'+ops+'" /><button class="bgen" id="btn'+ops+'">X</button></div>');
          }
        });
  }
  function textinside(option){
  var ops = $('#multichecks option:selected');
        var selected = [];
        $(ops).each(function() {
          selected.push([$(this).val()]);
        });
        $('#9MMM').html('');

        $(selected).each(function(index, ops) {
          if (ops){
            $('#9MMM').html($('#9MMM').html() +'<label class = "custom_label_div2" id="lbl'+ops+'"> '+ops+'; </label>');
          }
        });
  }
  $('#multichecks').multiselect({
      nonSelectedText: 'Check an option!',
      maxHeight: 200,
      numberDisplayed: 2,
      enableFiltering: true,
      enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
      includeSelectAllOption: true,
      selectAllText: 'Check all!',
      onChange: function (option) {
        textinside(option);
        generate(option)
      },
      onSelectAll: function() {
        textinside(option);
        generate(option)
      }
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.bgen', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    var str = this.id.replace("btn","");
    $("#multichecks").multiselect('deselect', str);
  });
});
```

```html
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "new.css" >
  </head>

  <body>
<!-- <input type="button" id = "btnAdd" onclick = "AddDropDownList()" value = "Add DropDownList" /> style="border:1px solid gray; width:150px;" -->

<hr />
<div class="box" id="box4">
  <h2> STEP 4 </h2>
  <strong>Where Condition :</strong>
  <div class="UZI" id="9MM" >
    <select id="multichecks" multiple="multiple"></select>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <strong>Selected Columns :</strong>
  <div class = "VSS" id = "9MMM" style="border:1px solid gray; width:150px;" >
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class = "inputBox" id="dvContainer"></div>
  <hr/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the select option value with your id to make it unique. And make sure to add dynamic html in both the `onChange` and `onSelectAll` methods.

```js
var options = [{
    "text": "New 1",
    "value": "[Invoice city]"
  },
  {
    "text": "New 2",
    "value": "[Invoice Date]"
  },
  {
    "text": "Ocv 3",
    "value": "val 3"
  },
  {
    "text": "Option 4",
    "value": "Value 4"
  },
  {
    "text": "Option 5",
    "value": "Value 5"
  }
];
var selectBox = document.getElementById('multichecks');

for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
  var option = options[i];
  selectBox.options.add(new Option(option.text, option.value, option.selected));
}


$(document).ready(function() {
 function generate(option){
  var ops = $('#multichecks option:selected');
        var selected = [];
        $(ops).each(function() {
          selected.push([$(this).val()]);
        });
        $('#dvContainer').html('');

        $(selected).each(function(index, ops) {
          if ("[Invoice city]" == ops || "[Invoice Date]" == ops){
            $('#dvContainer').html($('#dvContainer').html() +'<div><label id="lbl'+ops+'">Label for '+ops+':</label><input type="text" id="txt'+ops+'" /><button class="bgen" id="btn'+ops+'">X</button></div>');
          }
        });
  }
  $('#multichecks').multiselect({
      nonSelectedText: 'Check an option!',
      maxHeight: 200,
      numberDisplayed: 2,
      enableFiltering: true,
      enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
      includeSelectAllOption: true,
      selectAllText: 'Check all!',
      onChange: function (option) {
        generate(option);
      },
      onSelectAll: function() {
        generate(option);
      }
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.bgen', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    var str = this.id.replace("btn","");
    $("#multichecks").multiselect('deselect', str);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- <input type="button" id = "btnAdd" onclick = "AddDropDownList()" value = "Add DropDownList" /> -->

  <hr />
  <div class="" id="">
    <strong>Where Condition :</strong>
    <div class="newa" id="newq">
      <select id="multichecks" multiple="multiple" onclick="test();"></select>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div id="dvContainer"></div>
    <hr/>
  </div>
```

Comment: You need to delegate the delete

Comment: hi @mplungjan can you please telll me  How can i modify my code such that when a X button i.e. remove button is clicked i want to remove that item from textbox and get the item unchecked from the dropdown.

Comment: Start with delegation: `$("#dvContainer").on("click",".delBtn",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $(this).closest("div").remove();});` and change the ids of the appended elements to class. I gave your delete button class="delBtn"

Comment: You should have `$('#dvContainer').append('<div><label id="lbl'+ops+'">Label for '+ops+':</label><input type="text" id="txt'+ops+'" /><button class="delBtn">X</button></div>');
 `

Comment: it does remove the inpurt and label, but it doesn't get unchecked from dropdown

Comment: Hello, I've updated the code with delete and unchecked functionality. Do check

Comment: Hello, @Mahbub Moon i have made the changes in my code.  when a X button i.e. remove button is clicked i want to remove that item from div section and get the item unchecked from the dropdown. It getting unchecked from the dropdown but does not remove it from another added div section by me . Can you please look at code

Comment: just replace `$("#multichecks").multiselect('deselect', str);` with `$("#multichecks").multiselect('deselect', str,true);` as this third parameter will trigger the change event on multiselect.